# POCO's - Are they associated with a specific Design Pattern (or patterns)?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Just wondering if the use of POCO's is associated with a particular design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POCOs are usually mentioned in the context of persistence ignorance. It can be used to implement the *Unit Of Work* pattern.

- **[The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)** by Jeremy Miller

Comment: Thanks Mark - I need to read the article properly, but at first glance it certainly looks like the 'right' answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that POCOs and POJOs are examples of the Single Responsibility Principle (principles are something like design patterns but more general). Say Person POCO can have one reponsibility: storing person data, but for example, if we add persistence to POCO, it won't be POCO any more, and will have 2 responsibilities: storing person data and persisting it.

Comment: I agree a POxO needs to "embody" (?) SRP, and that adding persistence to it would void that.  Beyond SRP, I was thinking there'd be some formal rules (in for form of a pattern) which made that sort of thing clear.